# How to get bars to retain their colors after reorder?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here I hope that a bar plot keeps the colors with the category.  The data may change from time to time---so the order of the bars may change---but I want to keep the colors with the (here) team names.

```
teams <- c("Riverside Reds", "Oakland Oranges", "Yucaipa Yellows", "Glendale Greens", "Bakersfield Blues", "Irvine Indigos", "Vacaville Violets")
rainbow_colors <- c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "#4B0082", "violet")
wins <- sample(64:104, length(teams))
df <- data.frame(teams, rainbow_colors, wins)

df %>%
  arrange(desc(wins)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(teams, wins),
       y = wins)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = teams),
       stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Team Standings",
   x = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = teams, 
    values = rainbow_colors)
```

[image: geom_bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]
All you need to do is specify names in `scale_fill_manual`:

```
 scale_fill_manual(breaks = teams, 
                values = setNames(rainbow_colors, teams))
```

**Full reproducible code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
teams <- c("Riverside Reds", "Oakland Oranges", "Yucaipa Yellows", "Glendale Greens", "Bakersfield Blues", "Irvine Indigos", "Vacaville Violets")
rainbow_colors <- c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "#4B0082", "violet")
wins <- sample(64:104, length(teams))
df <- data.frame(teams, rainbow_colors, wins)



df %>%
  arrange(desc(wins)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(teams, wins),
             y = wins)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = teams),
           stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Team Standings",
       x = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = teams, 
                    values = setNames(rainbow_colors, teams))
```